# convert string into java.util.date format in java

Tags: java, string, datetime, date, date-conversion

am having a string like this.

```
Thu Oct 07 11:31:50 IST 2010
```

I want to convert this into its exact date time format to store it in SQL.

Am familiar with so many string to date conversions like the following.

```
String dateString = "2001/03/09";

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
```

But i need to convert a string like `Thu Oct 07 11:31:50 IST 2010`
  into its Date format with timestamp.

Can anyone explain the proper way of converting this into its java.util.Date format.?

Comment: Could you please clarify: you are asking about date format string to parse this date?

Comment: yea..i just want to convert the strig Thu Oct 07 11:31:50 IST 2010
into its corresponding date format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

For future reference read up on the SimpleDateFormat class:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 3):

Use this [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) -'`EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy`'

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy")
                      .parse("Thu Oct 07 11:31:50 IST 2010");
System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do like below

```
   String str = "Thu Oct 07 11:31:50 IST 2010";
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss   'IST' yyyy");
   SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
   System.out.println(sdf2.format(sdf.parse(str)));
```